# Java HashMap Iteration not showing comparison between key and variable

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I am trying to iterate through a HashMap and when  a duplicate key (key=node coord) is detected I want to give the new node  with the same key( coord ) the same nodeID( Hasmap value ). Here is my problem codeblock and my output. As you can see it outputs that the key( keys) and the new key(finishedLine3) have the same value but it will not go into the "if" statement and change the nodeIDs.

HISTORY: I am comparing with " == " here but have also tried if(keys.equal(finishedLine3)) and get the same result.

I also show in the output that 
nodes key:  -86.88642133.035899 nodes value: 00000001
and
nodes key: -86.88642133.035899 nodes value: 00000010
are the same but at no time during the iteration does my logic allow these comparison of the two exact keys go into my "if" block.

Here is my code:

```
    package com.KatsProject.net;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
public class MakeFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00000000");
         Integer numWords = 0;
         Integer numLines = 1;
         Integer numNodes =0;
         Integer nodeID =0;
         Integer counter=0;
         String nodesID2 ="";
         String newNodeID="";
         String  header = "road_id      #_of_nodes          node_id         node_x_coord        node_y_coord    ... end of list";
         String finishedLine1 = " ";
         String finishedLine2 = " ";
         String finishedLine3 = " ";
         String finishedLine34 = " ";
         String finishedLine = " ";
         String roadID= "";
         String roadID2= "";
         String match=" ";
         String match2=" ";
         String temp=" ";
         BufferedReader br= null;
         BufferedWriter bw= null;
         HashMap<String, String> nodes = new HashMap<String, String>();
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\gary\\Desktop\\roads.txt"));
         try {
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\gary\\Desktop\\Secretfile"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error writing file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         String line = null;
         while( (line = br.readLine())!= null )
         {   
            if(numLines > 1){
            numWords =0;  
            nodeID +=1; 
            newNodeID= df.format(nodeID);
            nodesID2 = newNodeID;
            String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            roadID = tokens[0]; // save roadID for comparison
            finishedLine1="";
              for(String s :tokens){
                  numWords+=1; 
                  if(numWords == 1){
                     // x.setRoadID(roadID);
                  }  
                  if(numWords ==2 ){
                     match += s;
                  }
                  if(numWords ==3 ){
                      match2 += s;
                      //System.out.println(match2+"this is match2 ,  " + match + "  this is match");
                  }
                  if(numWords == 4 ){
                      finishedLine3 += s;               //for hash table
                      finishedLine3.trim();
                      finishedLine1 += s;
                      finishedLine1 += "      ";
                      //System.out.println(x.getX_coord()+ "   this is x_coord.");
                  }
                  if(numWords == 5){
                      finishedLine3 += s;                 //for hash table
                      finishedLine3.trim();
                      finishedLine1 += s;
                      finishedLine1 += "      ";
                      String key =finishedLine3;
                      //System.out.println("It is    " + nodes.containsKey(key)+ "  that the nodeID for the key :    "+ finishedLine3 + "    is:     " + nodes.get(key)+ "      "+ key );
                      //System.out.println(finishedLine3+ " Is this the line that also includes the roadID #?");
                      //nodes.put(key,newNodeID );
                      Set<String> keySet = nodes.keySet();
                      Iterator<String> keyIterator = keySet.iterator();
                      //System.out.println("Another iteration starts , this is iteration :       "+ nodeID);
                      bw.write("Another iteration starts , this is iteration :       "+ nodeID);
                      bw.write("\n");
                      while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                          String keys = keyIterator.next();
                          //System.out.println( keys);
                          //System.out.println(" nodes key: " + keys + " nodes value: " + nodes.get(keys));
                          //System.out.println("Is keys:  "+keys + " equal to finishedLine3 :  " +finishedLine3);
                          if (keys.equals(finishedLine3))
                          {

                              //System.out.println( "This is finishedLine3 :  "+finishedLine3 +" , and it is equal to:  " + keys);  
                              newNodeID = nodes.get(keys);
                              // System.out.println(nodes.get(key) + "     this is nodes.get(key) ");
                              //System.out.println(nodes.get(keys) + "     this is nodes.get(keys) ");
                              //finishedLine2+=nodes.get(finishedLine3);
                              finishedLine3="";
                              }
                      }
                      nodes.put(key,newNodeID );
                      match2="";
                      match="";

                   }
              }
              if ((!(roadID.equals(roadID2)))&&(match.equals(match2)))
              {
                   finishedLine+= roadID;
                   finishedLine+= "              ";
                   finishedLine+=numNodes;
                   finishedLine+= "             ";
                   finishedLine+=finishedLine2;
                   finishedLine+="...end of list \n";
                   bw.write(finishedLine);
                   bw.write("\n");
                   finishedLine=" ";
                   finishedLine2=" ";
                   finishedLine3=" ";
                   numNodes=0;
                   roadID2 = roadID;
                   //roadID2 = x.roadID;
                   match="";
                   match2="";

              }
              if((roadID.equals(roadID2))||roadID2==""){
                  //finishedLine2+= x.getNodeID();
                  finishedLine2+= newNodeID;
                  //System.out.println( " This is finishedLine2 after inserting newNodeID: "+ newNodeID+"   "+ finishedLine2);
                  //System.out.println(newNodeID + "     this is newNodeID copied to finishedLine2 string."+finishedLine2+" checking to see if newNOdeID was changed in string");
                  //System.out.println(" This is finishedLine1: " +finishedLine1);
                  finishedLine2+="          ";
                  finishedLine2 += finishedLine1;
                  finishedLine2+="              ";
                  //System.out.println( " This is finishedLine2: "+ finishedLine2);
                  numNodes+=1;
                  finishedLine1="";
                  match2="";
                  match="";
                  //System.out.println("this is in if statement");
              }
              finishedLine3 = "";
         }
         else{
              System.out.print(header+"\n");
               bw.write(header + "\n");
               numLines+=1;
          }
          roadID2 = roadID;
          match="";
          match2="";

       }    
       br.close(); 
    }    

}
```

And here is my output:

```
        road_id     #_of_nodes          node_id         node_x_coord        node_y_coord    ... end of list
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  1  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88651833.035997? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  2  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88657833.03605? 
This is keys:  -86.88651833.035997and this is the :  3  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88651833.035997 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88657833.03605? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  4  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88666833.03609? 
This is keys:  -86.88651833.035997and this is the :  5  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88651833.035997 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88666833.03609? 
This is keys:  -86.88657833.03605and this is the :  6  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88657833.03605 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88666833.03609? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  7  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674233.03608? 
This is keys:  -86.88651833.035997and this is the :  8  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88651833.035997 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674233.03608? 
This is keys:  -86.88666833.03609and this is the :  9  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88666833.03609 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674233.03608? 
This is keys:  -86.88657833.03605and this is the :  10  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88657833.03605 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674233.03608? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  11  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679433.036037? 
This is keys:  -86.88651833.035997and this is the :  12  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88651833.035997 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679433.036037? 
This is keys:  -86.88674233.03608and this is the :  13  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88674233.03608 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679433.036037? 
This is keys:  -86.88666833.03609and this is the :  14  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88666833.03609 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679433.036037? 
This is keys:  -86.88657833.03605and this is the :  15  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88657833.03605 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679433.036037? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  16  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679133.035966? 
This is keys:  -86.88651833.035997and this is the :  17  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88651833.035997 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679133.035966? 
This is keys:  -86.88674233.03608and this is the :  18  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88674233.03608 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679133.035966? 
This is keys:  -86.88679433.036037and this is the :  19  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88679433.036037 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679133.035966? 
This is keys:  -86.88666833.03609and this is the :  20  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88666833.03609 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679133.035966? 
This is keys:  -86.88657833.03605and this is the :  21  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88657833.03605 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88679133.035966? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  22  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674333.03591? 
This is keys:  -86.88651833.035997and this is the :  23  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88651833.035997 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674333.03591? 
This is keys:  -86.88679133.035966and this is the :  24  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88679133.035966 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674333.03591? 
This is keys:  -86.88674233.03608and this is the :  25  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88674233.03608 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674333.03591? 
This is keys:  -86.88679433.036037and this is the :  26  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88679433.036037 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674333.03591? 
This is keys:  -86.88666833.03609and this is the :  27  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88666833.03609 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674333.03591? 
This is keys:  -86.88657833.03605and this is the :  28  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88657833.03605 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88674333.03591? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  29  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:  -86.88651833.035997and this is the :  30  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88651833.035997 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:  -86.88674333.03591and this is the :  31  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88674333.03591 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:  -86.88679133.035966and this is the :  32  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88679133.035966 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:  -86.88674233.03608and this is the :  33  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88674233.03608 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:  -86.88679433.036037and this is the :  34  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88679433.036037 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:  -86.88666833.03609and this is the :  35  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88666833.03609 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:  -86.88657833.03605and this is the :  36  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:  -86.88657833.03605 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88668133.035885? 
This is keys:   -86.88642133.035899and this is the :  37  iteration through the while loop
Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88642133.035899?
```

Thanks to anyone that can help and hope I was clear and concise enough.

Comment: What is the type of finishedLine3? Your keys have type String, so any comparison with any other type will result in false. You also should avoid doing comparison of non primitive types with `==`.

Comment: Please post more complete code, that would help in finding out what's wrong

Comment: @user3799901 what is finishedLine3

Comment: finishedLine3 is a String object. The code is 165 lines  I dont think you want all of that. Everything works great except that it wont go into this "if" statement when i compare two string objects when they are equal. I have used keys.equals(finishedLine3) and get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

While using the `==`, you normally imply that the objects are the same. Therefore, avoid using `==` for objects in favor of `Object equals()` but use `==` for primitives. In your case, you should be using `keys.equals(finishedLine3)` as these are two different objects. In your problem above, you haven't shown initialization of the `finishedLine3` which is probably causing the wrong behavior.

Comment: I have used the keys.equals(finishedLine) as I explained and get the same thing. FinishedLine is initialized and as you can see in the output has a value .

Comment: Where is the initialization of your `finishedLine` String object?

Comment: You're giving us very little code snippet to warrant any assistance. If you organize your code and add more details, perhaps we can be able to assist you without guessing what you mean.

Comment: I have included all of my code, thank you for your feedback Patwanjau.

Comment: I was using .equal instead of .equal's' ... thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you replicated the output of the code you have run. I would suggest you use Object equals() when comparing two string objects. But what I could see in your code is that there is a leading blank space in your key(" -86.88642133.035899" instead of "-86.88642133.035899"). So you could try avoiding this while creating the HashMap or if you are getting your input from some file you could trim the string, here is a link to the documentation-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get this same code everytime , my code works perfect other than my comparison of the two String objects. As I explained I used the keys.equal(finishedLine3) and got the exact same results  but I will use your advice and always use the .equals() for String objects.

Comment: Did you check if the string had any leading spaces? Because "    abc" wouldn't be same as "abc". For the first key in the output "Is keys:   -86.88642133.035899 equal to finishedLine3 :  -86.88642133.035899" there is an extra leading space character in the front. It is a minor detail but I wanted to check if you considered that possibility.

Comment: I updated my code( it has all of my program code) to show how I used the Object.trim(). Can you see if I used it right and if you see anything else I may have missed?

Comment: I see that you have used trim for your finishedLine3 variable, could you do the same for the keys that are being inserted? Also the way trim() method is different from what you have done. Trim() method returns the string with no leading or trailing spaces but it wont the value stored in the variable. So could try you the following - 
finishedLine3 = finishedLine3.trim(), also key = key.trim()

Comment: this is my output now, worked on it for hours trying to figure out why nodes.get(keys); is returning the value of the one it  is comparing it to instead of the first instance.

Comment: nodes.get(keys)  is giving the last instance  00000010 ,instead of the first 00000001. In other words its not  giving the new node the same ID as the duplicate/same instance.

Comment: Ok. I was completely lost on what you were trying to achieve, so I took a look at your code and I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to store the duplicate values with the same node ID? Or is it that if there is a duplicate/same value then the key of that instance should be the same?

Comment: Is it just one if that's not working as you intended to, then which one is it? Syntactically all everything seems fine to me. Let me know what if you think is not working I'll take a look into that one. Tried looking at your code and my head started to spin cause it doesn't have any indentation.

Comment: What I am doing is reading in a file line by line. i am taking out unwanted data and outputting it to a useful file for my own needs.  The existing file has no unique node ID so I want to give the new file a node with a unique ID. The hashmap is just for comparing for other nodes with same key, if it has the same key , output the node to my new file with the same ID and not worry about putting duplicate node into hashmap. Inside my if statement I have "  newNodeID = nodes.get(keys);" this is to change the value of the output to the file in the statement:

Comment: if((roadID.equals(roadID2))||roadID2==""){
                 
                         finishedLine2+= newNodeID;

Comment: My problem is that inside the if statement where it changes "newNodeID" is that its giving the newNodeIDthe value of the existing node/key being made (0000010) , not of the first instance that it found (0000001).

Comment: HashMap takes a pair of <Key, Value>, over here you are trying to create the key as nodeID in increments of 1 in the decimal format of "00000000" and the Value would be your "Key" from the files i.e the node data itself. So when you are trying to compare the <Key, Value> pair of hashmap in your case it would be <Generated nodeID, Key value taken from the file>, you are taking the keys of the hashmap i.e "Generated nodeID" and comparing it with the value. Could you check if your programs runs well if you change nodes.keySet() to nodes.values(). FYI nodes.values() returns a collection object.

Comment: Here is how I am creating the hashmap : nodes.put(key,newNodeID );..... am I not creating a key that is in the same form as finishedLine3(-86.88679133.035966) ? and a value in the form of '00000000' ? If so that is what I want, or are you saying to change them around and try to find when two values are the same and give it the same key? If so I will try that , wish me luck !

Comment: Assuming "if (keys.equals(finishedLine3))" this is where you are going wrong and inserting "nodes.put(key,newNodeID );" without executing this "newNodeID = nodes.get(keys);". Have you tried to throw an user defined exception inside the while loop so that it'll skip the insertion part(i.e., this line "nodes.put(key,newNodeID );"). Its not a clean way to do it, but you could give it a shot.

Comment: The while loop and the three lines following it would be in a try block and you throw for example lets say "yourException" inside the "if". This would skip the entire unnecessary iterations of while after finding one match and lets the previous value be in peace. And include a catch below the while loop + the three lines.

Comment: If the above doesn't work then the .equals itself is returning to be false even for the values it supposed to return true. Then I would suggest to debug your code with the help of breakpoints. I know debugging and testing is a drag but sometimes it has to be done.

Comment: You can not put the ' nodes.put(k,v) ' in the while loop since the loop runs only when there is something in the hashmap.It cant go into while loop for comparisons if nothing is in the hashmap.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you move 'nodes.put(k, v)' into the while loop. I was suggesting you break out of while loop when the condition is satisfied. But just breaking out of the loop will execute the next three lines that show up after which we don't want. So here is what I proposed: **try{ while{ throw exceptionhere} your three lines involving the insertion} catch(exceptonhere){ do nothing i here or match, match2 if you need to**} that way insertion of duplicates will all together be skipped.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of using .contains() to get only the instances that exist before going into the while loop...this is what I did:

Comment: if(nodes.containsKey(finishedLine3))
             {  
             while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
               counter+=1;
               String keys = keyIterator.next();
               keys=keys.trim();
               String varchar= nodes.get(keys);
               if (keys.equals(finishedLine3))
            {
                newNodeID= varchar;
                nodes.put(finishedLine3, newNodeID );
                finishedLine3="";
            }
              }
             }
             else{
             nodes.put(finishedLine3,newNodeID );
             }

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the question complete so that others can refer to it when they come across the same issue.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.